# Problema de visibilidad en panel hijo

Tags: c#

Mi problema es que tengo en un form de C# dos paneles en la misma ubicacion y automaticamente el de arriba lo transforma en hijo del primero, por lo que cuando intento Panel2.Visible= True ; Panel1.Visible=False ; no me muestra ninguno ya que Form 2 es hijo de Panel1.Como hago para que eso no me suceda ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si el formulario que estas ocultando primero es el padre y despues haces visible el hijo no se te va a ejecutar porque recuerda que el codigo se ejecuta en un orden, Por lo que deverias primero decir Panel2.Visible= True; y despues poner this.Hide; para que el formulario se cierre pero ojo si pones this.close; no se te va a ejecutar tampoco

Comment: Gracias exactamente eso era lo q me pasaba ya esta resuelto .

Answer (score 0):

Para llamar a un nuevo formulario, deberás instanciarlo no ocultarlo mediante la propiedad visible. Deberás hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```
FormNew Fn = new FormNew(); //instancias el nuevo formulario
this.Hide(); //haces que se oculte el formulario principal
Fn.ShowDialog(); //haces que se muestre el nuevo formulario
this.Show(); //le indicas que cuando se cierre el nuevo formulario vuelva a ser visible el formulario principal.
```